# Insert items into database using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to update my database using AJAX

This is my ajax function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if($('#category').val()===''){
        alert('Please enter a category name.')
    }
    else{
        var category = $('#category').val();
        var subcategory = $('#subcategory').val();

        alert(category);
        alert(subcategory);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Admin_controller/insertCategory",
            data:{ category:category, subcategory:subcategory },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('You can now add items.');
            }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Here is my Admin_controller

```
public function insertCategory(){
    $category = $this->input->post('category');
    $subcategory = $this->input->post('subcategory');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subcategory', 'Subcategory', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view('ADMIN_ADDCategory');
    }
    else{
        $category_id = $this->admin_model->insertCategory($category);
        $this->admin_model->insertSubcategory($category_id, $subcategory);
    }
}
```

Here is my model

```
function insertCategory($category){
    $data = array(
        'category' => $category,
        'status' => 1
    );
    $this->db->insert('category', $data);
    $this->db->insert('category', $data);

    $id = $this->db->insert_id(): //assign the last inserted id to variable $id
    return $id;
}

function insertSubcategory($category_id, $subcategory){
    $data = array(
        'category_id' => $category_id,
        'subcategory' => $subcategory,
        'status' => 1
    );
    $this->db->insert('subcategory', $data);
}
```

When I click the button that is supposed to trigger the AJAX function it shows the `alert('You can now add items.');` but it doesn't update my database with my required values.

I already tried doing

```
var category = $('#category').val();
var subcategory = $('#subcategory').val();

alert(category);
alert(subcategory);
```

to view if it gets my inputs and yes it does. After the alert it just refreshes my page.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request is not having any POST data to send. Yes it is making a POST request to the controller, but no data is being sent.
The category and subcategory variables in Admin controller will be false in that case, resulting in the issue.

You need to send category and subcategory as data in your AJAX request:

In your JS code, you haven't done validation if subcategory is there or not.

Also, before making the AJAX request, you will need to declare two variables category and subcategory. This is how the AJAX request will look like (I haven't done any validations).

```
var category = $('#category').val();
var subcategory = $('#subcategory').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:{ category:category, subcategory:subcategory},
    url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/Admin_controller/insertCategory",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('You can now add items.');
    }
});
```

Apart from that, you can also optimise your code by changing this in your model:

```
    $this->db->insert('category', $data);
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->where('category', $category);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

into this:

```
    $this->db->insert('category', $data);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
```

If any doubts, let me know.

Comment: I did this sir but even though it updates my `category` table, it doesn't update my `subcategory` table. But there are values in my `var category` and `var subcategory` when i alert them.

Comment: $category_id will have an int, not an array after using insert_id.
You need to do the below in Admin controller, instead of using $category_id[0]->id.
Use this: 
$this->admin_model->insertSubcategory($category_id, $subcategory);

Comment: Yes i have done that in my Admin_controller. But it is still the same. I will update my post regarding the changes I have made.

Comment: Just to let you know, my javascript codes are not in my view. They are in a seperate js file that are imported in my view.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes**

1. Ajax URL is wrong. And its chnaged
2. In your ajax you are not passing any post values to controller
3. In model added last insert id instead of the select
4. Improved some areas

---

**In Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#category').val()==='' AND $('#subcategory').val() === ''){
            alert('Fields should not be empty')
        }
        else{
            var category = $('#category').val();
            var subcategory = $('#subcategory').val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"post",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Admin_controller/insertCategory",
                    data:{ category:category, subcategory:subcategory},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        alert('You can now add items.');
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```

**In Model**

```
function insertCategory($category){
    $data = array(
        'category' => $category,
        'status' => 1
    );
    $this->db->insert('category', $data);

    $id = $this->db->insert_id(); # get last insert ID
    return  $id
}

function insertSubcategory($category_id, $subcategory){
    $data = array(
        'category_id' => $category_id,
        'subcategory' => $subcategory,
        'status' => 1
    );
    $this->db->insert('subcategory', $data);
}
```

**Admin_controller**

```
public function insertCategory(){
    $category = $this->input->post('category');
    $subcategory = $this->input->post('subcategory');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subcategory', 'Subcategory', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view('ADMIN_ADDCategory');
    }
    else{
        $category_id = $this->admin_model->insertCategory($category);
        $this->admin_model->insertSubcategory($category_id, $subcategory);
    }
}
```

Comment: This reads more like a big game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why did you change it?

Comment: @Quentin added the change log. Thnx (y)

Comment: I did this sir but the problem is still there. I get the values from `category` and `subcategory` and it still goes through the `success:function(data)` coz it displays ` alert('You can now add items.');` but it still doesn't update my tables.